# Ransack : Rails 6 > PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR with custom foreign_key defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, ransack

I have 2 models. Lets say

1. modelA
2. modelB

The relationship is as below between them

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :distributor, class_name: 'ModelB', foreign_key: 'distributor_id'
  belongs_to :asset_manager, class_name: 'ModelB', foreign_key: 'asset_manager_id'
end
```

```
class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
end
```

ModelB has an attribute named "name" and I want to perform a search on it from ModelA

So when I perform this query:

```
ModelA.ransack(distributor_name_or_asset_manager_name_cont: "some name")
```

it throws below error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "asset_managers_model_A"
```

And it tries to fire the below query in the database

```
model_B.name ILIKE "some name" OR asset_managers_model_A.name ILIKE "some name"
```

So, is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the ransack gem open issues, I found that this is already reported. I am facing the issue with Rails 6.0.2 and Ransack version 2.4.0

After upgrading my rails version to 6.1.0 (latest version) it all works fine.

Below are the links to open issue in the Ransack gem git hub repo

1. https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/1119
2. https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/1144
3. https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/1182